# Need help initializing below array

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

Write a declaration for an 8*8 char array named chess_board. Include an 
initialize that puts the following data into the array (one character per array 
element):

```
r n b q k b n r 

p p p p p p p p 

‧ ‧ ‧ ‧

 ‧ ‧ ‧ ‧ 

‧ ‧ ‧ ‧ 

 ‧ ‧ ‧ ‧ 

P P P P P P P P 

R N B Q K B N R
```

Answer (score 3):

You can declare the array with initializer: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_(programming)

```
const char chess_board[][8] = {
        { 'r', 'n', 'b', 'q', 'k', 'b', 'n', 'r' },

        { 'p', 'p', 'p', 'p', 'p', 'p', 'p', 'p' },

        { '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.' },

        { '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.' },

        { '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.' },
        { '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.' },
        { 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P' },
        { 'R', 'N', 'B', 'Q', 'K', 'B', 'N', 'R' },
    };
```